# Как настроить свои переходы?

Tags: jquery, css, css3, bxslider

Как карусели [bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified) (плагин для jQuery) настроить свои переходы между слайдами?
Там есть переходы по слайдам вперёд и назад, мне нужно использовать свои кнопки формата картинки.

Answer (score 2):

Иконки "влево" "вправо" находятся в спрайте http://bxslider.com/lib/images/controls.png
В CSS установлены здесь

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-next { 
background: url("http://bxslider.com/lib/images/controls.png") -43px -32px no-repeat transparent;
right: 10px;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-prev { 
background: url("http://bxslider.com/lib/images/controls.png") 0px -32px no-repeat transparent;
left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: окей, и ты предлагаешь менять путь к картинкам прямо в либе?

Comment: А почему нет? В чем проблема...

Comment: А если выйдёт новая версия слайдера и его захотят обновить?
опять лезть в либу и писать путь к картинкам?

Comment: Хорошо, не пиши ссылки, а открой папку images и подмени спрайт controls.png на свой спрайт, выйдет новая версия, картинку опять подменишь...